# How do i save a c program using geany? Error: The file on disk may now be truncated

Tags: permissions, c, geany

Everytime I try to save a file in my usb Ubuntu using Geany, it gives me the following error message :

```
 Error opening file '/home/ricky/INT/1406641703/Lab02/Hallo.c':  
 Permission denied  
The file on disk may now be truncated!
```

I also cannot write a C program using `vim` in terminal. Any help is appreciated

Comment: have you used vi before t write any other code

Comment: yes, i've tried using vi in terminal, it gives me :    "Hallo.c" E212: Can't open file for writing
Press ENTER or type command to continue

Comment: `Permission denied` are you sure you have mounted your stick with correct permissions? It doesn't look like this. Can you add your output of mount to this question?

Comment: Yes --- the stick should be under `/media/ricky/INT...` --- please tell us how do you mount (get acces to)  the USB drive. Something is broken there (no related to `gedit` nor `vi`).